# PHP round time() up (future) to next multiple of 5 minutes

Tags: php, time, rounding

How do I round the result of `time()` up (towards the future) to the next multiple of 5 minutes?

Comment: nearest in the future or in the past?

Comment: @hakre: you forget the option for the nearest nearest, like usual rounding works. At 14:06, the nearest 5 minutes is in the past (14:05) and at 14:08, the nearest 5 minutes is in the future (14:10). In the original (non-edited) question, it was clearly the expected email delivery time (which must be in the future).

Comment: @JarrodRoberson That's MySQL, this is just PHP.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

```
 $now = time();     
 $next_five = ceil($now/300)*300;
```

This will give you the next round five minutes (always greater or equal the current time).

I think that this is what you need, based on your description.

Comment: OP asked for "nearest"  This will round up even if one second above a five minute mark.

Comment: I know, that why I added the comment. by the description of his need what he's looking for is the NEXT round 5 minutes, and not the nearest (he said "script that would tell them when their email would be delivered" - future tense). maybe I'm wrong but that what I understood

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, I did indeed mean in the future and shortly after posting this realised that ceil existed, but thanks for the input!

Answer (score 17):

Try:

```
$time = round(time() / 300) * 300;
```

Comment: While the OP asked for "nearest" the context is described as future.

Comment: This solution is valid for nearest. Use `round` for nearest and `ceil` for nearest future. While we're here, `floor` should work for last.

Answer (score 11):

Try this function:

```
function blockMinutesRound($hour, $minutes = '5', $format = "H:i") {
   $seconds = strtotime($hour);
   $rounded = round($seconds / ($minutes * 60)) * ($minutes * 60);
   return date($format, $rounded);
}

//call 
 blockMinutesRound('20:11');// return 20:10
```

Answer (score 3):

For people using [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) (such as people using Laravel), this can help:

```
/**
 * 
 * @param \Carbon\Carbon $now
 * @param int $nearestMin
 * @param int $minimumMinutes
 * @return \Carbon\Carbon
 */
public static function getNearestTimeRoundedUpWithMinimum($now, $nearestMin = 30, $minimumMinutes = 8) {
    $nearestSec = $nearestMin * 60;
    $minimumMoment = $now->addMinutes($minimumMinutes);
    $futureTimestamp = ceil($minimumMoment->timestamp / $nearestSec) * $nearestSec; 
    $futureMoment = Carbon::createFromTimestamp($futureTimestamp);
    return $futureMoment->startOfMinute();
}
```

These test assertions pass:

```
public function testGetNearestTimeRoundedUpWithMinimum() {
    $this->assertEquals('2018-07-07 14:00:00', TT::getNearestTimeRoundedUpWithMinimum(Carbon::parse('2018-07-06 14:12:59'), 60, 23 * 60 + 10)->format(TT::MYSQL_DATETIME_FORMAT));
    $this->assertEquals('2018-07-06 14:15:00', TT::getNearestTimeRoundedUpWithMinimum(Carbon::parse('2018-07-06 14:12:59'), 15, 1)->format(TT::MYSQL_DATETIME_FORMAT));
    $this->assertEquals('2018-07-06 14:30:00', TT::getNearestTimeRoundedUpWithMinimum(Carbon::parse('2018-07-06 14:12:59'), 30, 10)->format(TT::MYSQL_DATETIME_FORMAT));
    $this->assertEquals('2018-07-06 16:00:00', TT::getNearestTimeRoundedUpWithMinimum(Carbon::parse('2018-07-06 14:52:59'), 60, 50)->format(TT::MYSQL_DATETIME_FORMAT));
    $this->assertEquals(Carbon::parse('tomorrow 15:00:00'), TT::getNearestTimeRoundedUpWithMinimum(Carbon::parse('16:30'), 60, 60 * 22 + 30));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For using [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/):

```
Carbon::createFromTimestamp(round(time() / 300) * 300)
```