# php - convert time() to a specific datetime

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to find a way to set a time in a `MySQL` database in the same format that php uses for `time()`.

For example, I am trying to find 12:30 PM (timezone is irrelevant for this so don't worry about time differences - the main piece is the **:30**).

I can use:

```
$nowTime = time();
```

to get the current time in `UNIX Timestamp`... but that won't get that exact `:30` unless I set it exactly at that time.

The DB has:

> Name: lastUpdate
>
> Type VARCHAR(30)

and I can use

```
$conn->query("UPDATE $tname SET....");
```

from there to update it.

Comment: So this isn't about formatting a datetime string, but capping or rounding the timestamp to the nearest(?) or last(?) half-hour?

Comment: rounding to the nearest 15M or 30M - yes

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10149792/php-round-to-nearest-5-minutes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to target a specific "subunit" of time, then you have to build the time string yourself, e.g.

```
$thirty_sec = date('Y-m-d h:i:30');
```

or

```
$now = new DateTime();
$now->setTime($now->format('h'), $now->format('i'), 30);
```