# PHP round datetime to nearest 5 interval

Tags: php, date, datetime, php-5.6

Following is the requirement, i have given datetime in format

> 11/14/2017 22:36

it should be round of to the nearest 5 minutes interval like following:

```
11/14/2017 22:36  => Output Should be 11/14/2017 22:40
11/14/2017 11:23  => Output Should be 11/14/2017 11:25
```

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19814427/php-datetime-round-up-to-nearest-10-minutes

Comment: i already checked this but doesnt seems perfect in my case

Comment: Hey, could you provide the current code you have?

Comment: Function for arbitrarily rounding PHP DateTimes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57399274/339440

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/26103014/3481654

The formula for that is

```
$time = round(time() / 300) * 300;
```

In complete working code

```
function nearest5Mins($time) {
  $time = (round(strtotime($time) / 300)) * 300;
  return date('Y-M-d H:i', $time);
}
echo nearest5Mins('11/14/2017 22:48');
echo "<br>";
echo nearest5Mins('11/14/2017 11:23');
```

[**DEMO**](https://eval.in/900326)